# What design pattern should be used for multiple providers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, design-patterns

I'm trying to write a localization system that supports different providers. (File, Database, and embedded file) These providers can be used at the same time. (e.g. both embedded files and databases records)

Everything is fine until it comes to the embedded files; embedded files in .NET are read-only. This means that the localization must support read-only operations for embedded files, besides this crud operations can be performed for normal files and database tables.

I tried to design it but got stuck at one point.

`ILocalizer` is for read-only providers. (Such as embedded files)

```
public interface ILocalizer
{
    LanguageInfo GetLanguage(string cultureName);
    IReadOnlyList<LanguageInfo> GetLanguages();

    string GetString(string name, string cultureName);
    IReadOnlyList<LanguageLocaleInfo> GetLocales(string cultureName);
}

public class Localizer : ILocalizer
{
    private readonly ILocalizerProvider _provider;

    public Localizer(ILocalizerProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public LanguageInfo GetLanguage(string cultureName)
    {
        return _provider.GetLanguage(cultureName);
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<LanguageInfo> GetLanguages()
    {
        return _provider.GetLanguages();
    }

    public string GetString(string name, string cultureName)
    {
        return _provider.GetString(name, cultureName);
    }
}
```

With `ILocalizerManager` changes can be reflected and the data can be read.

```
public interface ILocalizerManager : ILocalizer
{
    void AddLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo);
    void RemoveLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo);
    void UpdateLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo);

    void AddLocale(LanguageLocaleInfo localeInfo);
    void UpdateLocale(LanguageLocaleInfo localeInfo);
}

public class LocalizerManager : Localizer, ILocalizerManager
{
    private readonly ILocalizerManagerProvider _localizerProvider;

    public LocalizerManager(ILocalizerManagerProvider localizationProvider, ILocalizerProvider localizerProvider) : base(localizerProvider)
    {
        _localizerProvider = localizationProvider;
    }

    public void AddLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo)
    {
        _localizerProvider.AddLanguage(languageInfo);
    }

    public void AddLocale(LanguageLocaleInfo localeInfo)
    {
        _localizerProvider.AddLocale(localeInfo);
    }

    public void RemoveLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo)
    {
        _localizerProvider.RemoveLanguage(languageInfo);
    }

    public void UpdateLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo)
    {
        _localizerProvider.UpdateLanguage(languageInfo);
    }

    public void UpdateLocale(LanguageLocaleInfo localeInfo)
    {
        _localizerProvider.UpdateLocale(localeInfo);
    }
}
```

These are the provider interfaces.

```
public interface ILocalizerProvider
{
    LanguageInfo GetLanguage(string cultureName);
    IReadOnlyList<LanguageInfo> GetLanguages();

    string GetString(string name, string cultureName);
}

public interface ILocalizerManagerProvider : ILocalizerProvider
{
    void AddLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo);
    void RemoveLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo);
    void UpdateLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo);

    void AddLocale(LanguageLocaleInfo localeInfo);
    void UpdateLocale(LanguageLocaleInfo localeInfo);
}
```

These are concrete providers.

```
public class DatabaseLocalizationProvider : ILocalizerManagerProvider
{
    private readonly IRepository<Language> _languageRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<LanguageLocale> _localeRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public DatabaseLocalizationProvider(IRepository<Language> languageRepository, IRepository<LanguageLocale> localeRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _languageRepository = languageRepository;
        _localeRepository = localeRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void AddLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo)
    {
        _languageRepository.Add(languageInfo.ToEntity());
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    public void AddLocale(LanguageLocaleInfo localeInfo)
    {
        _localeRepository.Add(localeInfo.ToEntity());
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    public LanguageInfo GetLanguage(string cultureName)
    {
        var language = _languageRepository.Get(g => g.Name == cultureName);
        if (language is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(cultureName);
        return language.ToModel();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<LanguageInfo> GetLanguages()
    {
        return _languageRepository.GetWhere(w => true).Select(s => s.ToModel()).ToImmutableList();
    }

    public string GetString(string name, string cultureName)
    {
        var locale = _localeRepository.Get(g => g.Culture == cultureName && g.Name == name);

        return locale?.Value ?? default!;
    }

    public void RemoveLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo)
    {
        var language = _languageRepository.Get(g => g.Name == languageInfo.Name);
        _languageRepository.Remove(language);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    public void UpdateLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo)
    {
        var language = _languageRepository.Get(g => g.Name == languageInfo.Name);

        language.Name = languageInfo.Name;
        language.DisplayName = languageInfo.DisplayName;
        language.Icon = languageInfo.Icon;

        _languageRepository.Update(language);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    public void UpdateLocale(LanguageLocaleInfo localeInfo)
    {
        var locale = _localeRepository.Get(g => g.Culture == localeInfo.CultureInfo.Name && g.Name == localeInfo.Name);

        locale.Value = localeInfo.Value;

        _localeRepository.Update(locale);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
}
```

```
public class ReadOnlyFileLocalizationProvider : ILocalizerProvider
{
    public LanguageInfo GetLanguage(string cultureName) { }

    public IReadOnlyList<LanguageInfo> GetLanguages() { }

    public string GetString(string name, string cultureName) { }
}
```

```
public class FileLocalizationProvider : ReadOnlyFileLocalizationProvider, ILocalizerManagerProvider
{
    public void AddLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo) { }

    public void AddLocale(LanguageLocaleInfo localeInfo) { }

    public void RemoveLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo) { }

    public void UpdateLanguage(LanguageInfo languageInfo) { }

    public void UpdateLocale(LanguageLocaleInfo localeInfo) { }
}
```

Reading and writing to files is easy, this is why method bodies are empty.

That's what I've done so far, I couldn't connect them all. I think I need to somehow store and access all providers somehow but how... I also need to use different providers at the same time.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to implement an interface that writes embedded files, but they are read-only. That doesn't sound like a problem that you can solve with a design pattern. Take design patterns out of the picture for a moment. Do you have a way to write embedded files? If the answer is no then that's the end of it. Or could that help to clarify the question?

Comment: No, like I said embedded files are read-only. How can you write on read-only files? I want to write to normal files. In this scenario if I provide an embedded-file it will perform read operations, if I provide a normal file or database table it will perform crud operations.

Comment: .NET's localization already supports multiple providers, not just resource files. [The docs contain examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization-extensibility?view=aspnetcore-7.0#localization-resources) of implementing IStringLocalizer to read from databases or JSON files. The [localization extensibility page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization-extensibility) page shows how you can customize how the language is identified or changes

Comment: The legacy ASP.NET also allowed multiple providers, going back all the way to ASP.NET 1. There are numerous implementations and extensions. Which stack and version are you using? WebForms? MVC? Razor Pages? ASP.NET Core? Blazor?

Comment: There's the **Read-only interface** pattern that shows how to separate two parts of an interface.